# Returning null values in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Given a set of products:

```
{catalog_id: 1, product_id: 1, price: 1.0 }
{catalog_id: 1, product_id: 3, price: 3.0 }
```

I want to find all the specified products, returning null values for products that don't exist.

For example:

```
db.products.find({"catalog_id": 1},{"product_id": [1,2,3]})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("514b211894562cfadbd93bc2"), "product_id" : 1, "price" : 1.0 }
{ "_id" : null, "product_id" : 2, "price" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("514b212194562cfadbd93bc3"), "product_id" : 3, "price" : 3.0 }
```

Is this possible?  Potentially using a projection to add the missing row back in?

Comment: I think you have to do that on the application layer.

Comment: A database isn't going to work out what products are missing from your list or how to return a document that doesn't exist.  Seems an odd use case, but as Philipp noted you would have to handle from your application code.

Comment: My use case is producing a padded array with nil values where missing products are.  My example query, while completely flawed, gives an example of providing ids so the db would know what is missing.  I'm thinking along the lines of SQL outer join (I understand that Mongo doesnt have joins, I want to simulate the behavior).